# Optimality minimizing stdev?

Tags: distributions, python, optimization

I have a set of values and I want to minimize stdev until say stdev <= 100. To do this I need to add or subtract from each data points, I want to know a method to do this efficiently (least no. of additions or subtractions). Preferably I want to be able to tweak the algorithm to only allow additions to the data points.

Comment: Adding a constant to random variable would not change its variance. Do you want to add different values to each observed case? If so, why would you want to do such thing? The easiest way to do so would be to subtract itself from each of the values so their variance would be exactly zero -- this is also an extreme example of why this does not make much sens.

Comment: At the moment it is quite unclear to me what you are asking. Do you think you could explain, perhaps by giving an example?

Comment: I want to add or subtract a different value from each data point until the dataset looks more uniform. This is for a game I'm working on, the data points represent the size of each player, I want to be able to tell each player how much they should grow or shrink so their team looks more homogeneous in size, sorry if I phrased the question wrongly.

Comment: If you literally want to make them uniform, you can transform them. It isn't clear to me that's what you really want, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample variance (square of standard deviation) is defined as

$$ \mathrm{var}(X) = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 $$

where $\bar x$ is sample mean. So to decrease variance you have to decrease the differences of each point from the mean

$$ r_i = x_i - \bar x $$

so if you subtract $x_i-r_i$ then

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - r_i - \bar x)^2 
  =  \sum_{i=1}^n (\bar x - \bar x)^2 
  = 0 $$

So to influence the variance you need to subtract $r_i$'s. You can also decrease the standard deviation by some fraction $\lambda \in [0,1]$ by subtracting $r_i \times (1-\lambda)$ from each $x_i$.